# Cant find self signed trusted certificate used by Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I have a very basic self-hosted .NET core 2.1 application with the following configuration:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
             .UseKestrel()
             .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

and very typical simple controller as follows:

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

This application works pretty fine when I test it and navigate to my HTTPS local endpoint port (44325 in my case):

https://localhost:44325/api/values

[image]

All good so far. Now I want to figure out where the certificate for this HTTPS connection is coming from since I am not using IIS Express and indeed the certificate doesn't belong to IIS Express:
[image]

I cant find above certificate in my certificate store when I search for its thumbprint. How does this certificate gets generated? Where can I find it? why does this certificate work in Edge and chrome but in Firefox its not trusted? is it generated on the fly?

My launch setting is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55894",
      "sslPort": 44325
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Experimental1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44325;http://localhost:55894",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*I am using the Experimental1 profile not the IIS Express and I see my little console when I run the application.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How does this certificate gets generated?

The .NET Core SDK generates the certificate the first time we run `dotnet new`

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-https-improvements/

> Where can I find it?

The SDK installs the ASP.NET Core HTTPS Development Certificate into the local user certificate store.

- [Open the Certificates Snap-in in the MMC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in).
- Certificates - Current User
- Find Certificates
- Search for `localhost`

[image]

> why does this certificate work in Edge and chrome but in Firefox its not trusted?

Indeed. Even after running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, Firefox does not trust the certificate and complains that, "*The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.*"

It might simply be that [Firefox no longer trusts self-signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550970/firefox-54-stopped-trusting-self-signed-certs). My workaround is to add a security exception.

[image]

Comment: In case it helps someone, I was hitting a similar problem to this presumably because I ran VS as a different AD user and had to generate a new cert.  After futzing with it for a while, I loaded up the MMC and saw a lot of certificates for localhost.  I deleted all of them, regenerated a new one and I was back in business.  My specific message was something like failed to find certificate at 'null'